# Nutch, Gora and MongoDB

Tags: nutch, gora

I'm trying to run Nutch (2.2.1) on Cygwin/Windows 7 with the latest version of Gora (0.5) so I can persist data to MongoDB datastore. I changed the Nutch-Site.XML File to include my Mongo property:

```
<property>
    <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore</value>
    <description>Default class for storing data</description>
</property>
```

My problem occurs when I try building the "gora-mongodb" project from the command line using Maven, 2 of the tests Fail - testCountQuery and testWordCount with the following permissions error:

```
14/12/12 19:09:28 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/12/12 19:09:28 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:MyPC cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-MyPC\mapred\staging\MyPC555128998\.staging to 0700
21738 [main] INFO org.apache.gora.GoraTestDriver - tearing down test
```

Is it possible to resolve this permissions error without moving over to Ubuntu etc?

Thanks,

O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know that in Nutch 2.2.1 you have to change the storage in `nutch/conf/gora.properties`.

About the testing error, you can do `mvn package -DskipTests`.

Comment: Hi Alfonso, thanks for your response. I didn't know that! I've updated the settings to map to my local instance of MongoDB and managed to build the "gora-mongodb" project using the mvn package command you provided and then copied the jar file into the apache-nutch-2.2.1\runtime\local\lib folder. I'm getting a new error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.gora.filter.SingleFieldV

Comment: The missing class is in gora-core module. You should copy gora-core.jar too :)